# No qualifying bean of type 'Package.TestDaoRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hey I am using spring boot version 2.3.4 for my web application. I am writing a JUNIT Integration test case for testing my controller, service and Repo using WebMvcTest.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(TestCotroller.class)
class ITTestController {

@Test
void test() {
    System.out.println("Test me ");
   // URL to call. controller and rest of the logic 
}

}
```

I am looking for minimum configuration to load so i have used @WebMvcTest.

This is my controller need to be tested

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = APIUrlConstants.VERSION + APIUrlConstants.TEST_CONTROLLER)
public class TestCotroller {
    @Autowired
    TestServiceInf testServiceInf;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = APIUrlConstants.TEST_DB, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> testDbStatus() {
        Long count = testServiceInf.testDbStatus();
        String responseMessage = "DB is up and running, total number of products count are --  " + count;
       return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = APIUrlConstants.TEST_APPLICATION, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> testApplicationStatus() {
        
        String responseMessage = testServiceInf.testApplication();
       return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
    
    }
```

The Service class

```
  @Service
public class TestServiceImpls implements TestServiceInf {
    
    @Autowired
    TestDaoRepo testDaoRepo;
    
    private static String responseMessage = "Application is up and running";
    
    @Override
    public Long testDbStatus() {
        
        Long countProduct = testDaoRepo.count();
        System.out.println(countProduct);
        return countProduct;
    }


    @Override
    public String testApplication() {
        
        return responseMessage;
    }

}
```

Repo class

```
@Repository
public interface TestDaoRepo extends JpaRepository<CpcMasterProduct, Long> { }
```

This is the error i am facing -

> No qualifying bean of type 'package.TestDaoRepo' available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please help me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`@WebMvcTest` won't instantiate `@Repository` beans. This is intentional in order to make the tests more lightweight and isolate the controller tests. Typically, you would replace your services with mocks for such tests.

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) for explanation.

In your case, your test would contain something like:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(TestCotroller.class)
class ITTestController {

@MockBean
private TestServiceInf serviceMock;

@Test
void test() {
    System.out.println("Test me ");
   // URL to call. controller and rest of the logic 
}

}
```

If you want to do integration tests, you shouldn't use `@WebMvcTest`.